# can I update a label using ajax, instead of a textbox?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I'm using ajax to update a textbox once the value in a drop down box has been selected. However, i only update/put text in it if certain conditions are met, so it looks rubbish when there is no message. I was thinking that having a label there would be much better, but is this possible? Can i have an empty label and just update the label text when needed?

Cheers
leddy

Edit:

I'm using php and when the drop down box is selected, I am querying a mysql db (in the reports.php page) - depending on what the result of that is, decides whether i update the textbox or not:

```
function getHTTPObject(){
   if (window.ActiveXObject) return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) return new XMLHttpRequest();
   else {
      alert("Your browser does not support AJAX.");
      return null;
   }
}   

// Change the value of the outputText field
function setOutput(){
    if(httpObject.readyState == 4){
        document.getElementById('outputText').value = httpObject.responseText;
    }

}


function checkException()
{

    httpObject = getHTTPObject();
    if (httpObject != null)
    {   
        httpObject.open("GET", "reports.php?exceptions="
                        +document.getElementById('exceptionsID').value+"&date1=" + document.getElementById('date1').value, true);
        httpObject.send(null);
        httpObject.onreadystatechange = setOutput;
    }
}

var httpObject = null;
```

the textbox is 'outputText' and is set in the setOutput() function

Hope this explains a little better

Cheers

Comment: Are you using a javascript library like JQuery?

Comment: You'll need only javascript (no ajax) if you don't need to get things from the server

Comment: no, I'm not using jQuery. and it's php, not asp.net - i'll edit the post and add some code now - thanks!

Comment: If by "label" you mean a `<span>` or a `<div>`, give either an ID and try `document.getElementById('yourlabel').innerHTML = httpObject.responseText;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should change the text of the label.

```
// Change the value of the outputText field
function setOutput(){
        if(httpObject.readyState == 4){
                document.getElementById('outputText').innerHTML= httpObject.responseText;
        }

}
```

I updated my original post to reflect the code that was provided. This assumes that you are using the `<label>`, `<div>`, or `<span>` tags

Answer (score 0):

Change the textbox into a span, and keep the id the same. Then change the code to set the innerHTML instead of the value:

```
// Change the value of the outputText field
function setOutput(){
        if(httpObject.readyState == 4){
                document.getElementById('outputText').innerHTML= httpObject.responseText;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using ASP.NET, yes you can. Using the Text property of the label.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to handle this without a textbox is to create a SPAN tag, give it an id of "outputText", and then change the innerText of the SPAN like this:

```
function setOutput() {
   if(httpObject.readyState == 4) {
       document.getElementById('outputText').innerText = httpObject.responseText;
   }
}
```

Inside your HTML, you'll have your label defined like this:

```
<span id="outputText">Some default text here</span>
```

Of course, some CSS styling of the SPAN might be a good thing, but that's another matter for another time.  Depending on your layout needs, a DIV tag may be better than a SPAN.

Comment: It looks like others beat me to the answer as I was typing mine up.  Using innerHTML will work just as well as innerText.  With innerHTML, you can throw some markup into the exception text and make it look really nice.